# preg_match: how to add function in

Tags: php, search

```html
<input name ='search' type ='text'  placeholder ='Search...'= '<?php  if (isset($_GET['submit'])){ echo $_GET ['learn']; }?>' >

$question=  "/\b(". $name. ")\b/i"; //<<My problem is here
//$name is an input

switch($name){
 case(preg_match($word, $question) ? true : false):
 //word is not the problem
 break;
```

ok, I have this and my question is how can I get the $word  to be in there. I tried a lot of ways but none of them seem to work. The $word is a function and i don't know how to put in and make the match to work. 
i also tried:

```html
case(preg_match("/\b<input name ='search' type ='text'  placeholder ='search' value = '<?php  if (isset($_GET['submit'])){ echo $_GET ['learn']; }?>' >\b/", $word) ? true : false):
```

the main problem is just putting a function inside the '/\b here \b/'
can you help

Comment: what is `$name` when your input field name is `search`...? need more clearance....

Comment: @Andrew - $name is the value entered to the search box, where i'm stuck on is how to make the entered value be compared to another bunch of words and if its found, it will output a definition. it will be compared to a phrase and if that phrase is found, it output the meaning. it works when i enter the full phrase, but i want it to output even when i search some WORDS, not letters. does that clarify some things?

Comment: This looks completely flawed. 1.) Where does `$word` come from, what does it contain? Is it a regex pattern within delimiters? *`$word` is a function...* a function? Please `var_dump($word);` or show its content. 2.) `$question` is a regex pattern. So you're matching a pattern with a pattern as input? 3.) `switch($name){` will probably never equal the return value of `preg_match` which can be `1`,`0` or `false` on error. You need to  `switch(1){` or `switch(true){` for achieving if-1-like behaviour... Please make the question better understandable for an appropriate answer.

Comment: Ok, forget about everything else, it already works, the only problem is matching the input '<input name ='search' type ='text'  placeholder ='Search...'= '<?php  if (isset($_GET['submit'])){ echo $_GET ['learn']; }?>' >

 ' with few words. now, you have to enter the entire phrase to get the result, i want it compare the input with the phrases and if a word is found, it outputs the definition.